# Check if window is in background Tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter, background, window

So, I'm trying to make an app on `tkinter`. I've just started learning how this module works.

In my app, I have a root window and a child (top leveled) window, and I set the child to be always on top. When I minimize my root window, the child window also minimizes, because I have defined that condition. My problem is when I select other window. When I do it, the child window still stays on top and I want to know if there is a way to know if my root window is in background, a.k.a.: I'm not currently working on it (like a `root.winfo_...` function).

I can provide other examples as I feel that I am not explaining my problem in a way that you understand.
I can also provide my code but I think that is now necessary.

Comment: Do you want to check whether the main window is iconified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Check if window is in background

Using `tk.self.winfo_containing(...` you can determine if a widget, here the `root` window, is shown at **Top Level**.
In this example, the center of the given window is used as **visible** point.

**Note**: While you move the window, the result may be `False`.

---

**Reference**:
- [Tkinter.Widget.winfo_containing-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_containing-method)

> Returns the widget at the given position, or None

---

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.is_toplevel()

    def is_toplevel(self):
        width, height, x, y = self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height(), \
                              self.winfo_rootx(), self.winfo_rooty()

        if (width, height, x, y) != (1, 1, 0, 0):
            is_toplevel = self.winfo_containing(x + (width // 2),
                                                y + (height // 2)
                                                ) is not None

            print('is_toplevel: {}'.format(is_toplevel))

        self.after(2000, self.is_toplevel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6 - Linux***
**Note**: Confirmed, works on *Windows*.
May not work on *MACOS*.