# How to do python top level app, but when you open a new program, it goes 1 level down

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes

I have used the following code, but i need to be able to open another program on top:

```
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check-if-window-is-in-background-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60442386)

Comment: I might be able to figure it out myslef using this and altough it isn't the same answer, It may do so, when i figure it out I'm marking solved

Comment: ***marking solved***: You have to write a answer by your own and accept it or close the question as **duplicate** or delete the question.